# Pull in datatable row information to modal if row input is greater than 0

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am currently trying to pull in the datatable row info into a dialog for the rows with qty input value greater than 0. I know with checkboxes if selected/true, it pulls all the same row information into a selected array to easily use. I'm trying to get this same functionality for input greater than 0.

Got checked boxes row info to get into dialog by using the selected array. Cant seem to figure out how to do the same (get that rows data) with inputs greater than 0

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xeVZKv?editors=1010

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
      v-model="selected"
      item-key="name"
      >
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
        <td v-if="props.item.qty < 2" style="width: 10%">
          <v-checkbox v-model="props.selected" primary hide-details></v-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td v-else style="display:inline-flex;">
          <v-text-field
            value="0"
            onclick="this.select()"
            type= "number"
            :max="props.item.Qty"
            :totalCount="props.item.Qty"
            min="0"
            :id="'inputCount' + props.index"
            style="width:40px; margin-left: 5px;"
            @change="counter()"
            ></v-text-field>
          <div style="padding-top: 15px; margin-left: 10px;">of {{ props.item.qty }}</div>
        </td>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:pageText="props">
        Lignes {{ props.pageStart }} - {{ props.pageStop }} de {{ props.itemsLength }}
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
    <v-layout row wrap class="">
      <v-flex xs4 class="text-xs-left">
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs4 class="text-xs-center">       
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs4 class="text-xs-right">
        <v-btn v-if="buyCounter < 1" color="primary" class="receiveButton" :disabled="buttonActivate" @click="buyModel()">Receive</v-btn>
        <v-btn v-else-if="buyCounter > 0 && buyCounter < 2" color="primary" class="receiveButton" :disabled="buttonActivate" @click="buyModel()">Receive {{ buyCounter }} Part</v-btn>
        <v-btn v-else-if="buyCounter > 1" color="primary" class="receiveButton" :disabled="buttonActivate" @click="buyModel()">Receive {{ buyCounter }} Parts</v-btn>
        <v-btn v-else color="primary" class="receiveButton" :disabled="buttonActivate">Receive</v-btn>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      inputCount: 0,
      selected: [],
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Qty Available', value: 'qty' }
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          qty: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          qty: 2
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          qty: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          qty: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          qty: 3
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          qty: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          qty: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          qty: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          qty: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          qty: 1
        }
      ]
    };
  },
    computed: {
        buttonActivate: function () {
            let count = 0;

            $('input[id^="inputCount"]').each(function (i, e) {
                let element = $(e).val();
                if (element == "") {
                    element = 0;
                }

                let eachCountInt = parseInt(element);

                count = eachCountInt + count;
            })

            this.inputCount = count;

            if (this.selected.length > 0 || this.inputCount > 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        buyCounter: function () {
            let count = this.selected.length + this.inputCount;

            return count;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        counter() {
            let count = 0;

            $('input[id^="inputCount"]').each(function (i, e) {
                let element = $(e).val();
                if (element == "") {
                    element = 0;
                }

                let eachCountInt = parseInt(element);

                count = eachCountInt + count;;
            })


            this.inputCount = count;
        },
    buyModel() {

    }
  }
  })
```

Overall looking to pull in all selected/greater than 0 info into the dialog to confirm before processing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your codepen is looping in a weird way

Comment: How do you mean?